# Orphan Kafka Connect Tasks

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am having a weird problem with my kafka connect cluster. Lately Ihave been seeing a lot of logs like this:

```
[Consumer clientId=connector-consumer-HGV6Yo_toDbSp3sCh9VtJw-1244665500-2, groupId=connect-HGV6Yo_toDbSp3sCh9VtJw-1244665500] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 117 : {HGV6Yo_toDbSp3sCh9VtJw-1244665500=UNKNOWN_TOPIC_OR_PARTITION}
```

These logs are coming from topics and connectors that were deleted already.
When trying to GET the connector or tasks through the REST interface it returns that it doesnt exist but when checking the kafka brokers consumer groups, I see that there are two consumer clients (tasks) that seem to be running:

```
GROUP                                              CONSUMER-ID                                                                                          HOST            CLIENT-ID                                                       #PARTITIONS     
connect-HGV6Yo_toDbSp3sCh9VtJw-1244665500 connector-consumer-HGV6Yo_toDbSp3sCh9VtJw-1244665500-1-a8015253-ba51-499e-9b48-880c893c2d5c /172.24.19.193  connector-consumer-HGV6Yo_toDbSp3sCh9VtJw-1244665500-1 0       
connect-HGV6Yo_toDbSp3sCh9VtJw-1244665500 connector-consumer-HGV6Yo_toDbSp3sCh9VtJw-1244665500-2-e354c341-6c3e-4554-8ac9-d1b7d7dfa524 /172.24.50.167  connector-consumer-HGV6Yo_toDbSp3sCh9VtJw-1244665500-2 0
```

Looks like there are orphan kafka connect tasks that seem to be still running.

I can use some help if anybody has encountered something similar or with an idea how this is possible?
Any way I can see delete specific tasks that seem to be exist without a connector?

Comment: Did you try to restart the connect java processes on the IP's listed?

Comment: Yes I did. Tasks restarted with the process. I am guessing the consumer client state is saved somewhere causing the tasks to restart as well.

Comment: I don't think so, but if you are on a relatively newer version of Kafka, then might be worth making a JIRA for a bug report